# Devise does not login when using ssl/https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, session-cookies

my problem comes from the fact that on my rails app I enabled config.force_ssl = true and because of that, everytime I login it simply redirects me back to my root path (index) without logging me in. The reason this happens is because I am securing my cookie with this in session_store.rb :

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_application_session', secure: true, httponly: true, same_site: :lax
```

If I don't have this, my cookies are not secured properly and are at risk from what I can see using online website security scanners.

Does anyone have an idea? I've tried pretty much everything in the related threads, but nothing worked. I was hoping for this one to be efficient, but it wasn't :

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  root_path :protocol => 'http://'
end
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you logging in on localhost or on a website with no SSL?

Comment: On a website from https:// with ssl/hsts enabled on cloudflare!

Comment: Why you want to land to root path with `http` after sign in?

Comment: Because with https it doesn't work. That's the problem, as far as I know it's because the cookies are being secured that it's simply redirecting to the index without logging in at all.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem yesterday.

The direct error is: when you opened a "https" page and fill the login form then submit, devise will redirect to a non-https(http) page. and then, it redirect to https page.

the root cause is: my nginx is not correctly configured.

1.I have to change the Rails' config:  ( config/environtments/production.rb )
add this line of code:

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

2.My nginx virtual site config looks like:

( notice the line of:  `proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto https;` )

```
 server {
      listen 80;
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
      server_name forum.yangqigong.cn;
  }

  server {
      listen 443 ssl;
      server_name forum.yangqigong.cn;

      ssl_certificate   /opt/ssl/8311517_forum.yangqigong.cn.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key  /opt/ssl/8311517_forum.yangqigong.cn.key;
      ssl_session_timeout 5m;
      ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE:ECDH:AES:HIGH:!NULL:!aNULL:!MD5:!ADH:!RC4;
      ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
      ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

      location / {
          proxy_pass          http://forum_yangqigong_cn_servers;
          proxy_redirect      default;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
          proxy_next_upstream http_502 http_504 error timeout invalid_header;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto https;    # 这里最最重要 
      }
      location ~ ^/assets|packs|system/ {
        root /opt/app/homeland/public;
        expires 1y;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        add_header ETag "";
        break;
      }

  }

  upstream forum_yangqigong_cn_servers{
         server localhost:3000;
  }
```